# How can I make a failed DotnetCore build break a Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, msbuild

We're in the process of moving builds to Dotnetcore from msbuild. We use a command like this to build in Jenkins:

```
dotnet msbuild OurProjectFile.csproj -args
```

This works great, except that when the build *fails*, it doesn't break the build. MSBuild-proper commands generate a *build failed* message that I think Jenkins is using to know to break the build...

How can I adjust my build (or Jenkins) so that failed dotnetcore builds break the Jenkins build they're called from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows sets the ENV variable `ERRORLEVEL` with the result of the previous command. You can use that combined with the "EXIT" command to exit with the proper errorlevel.

`exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%` after your dotnet command will cause the build to fail if dotnet fails. (You might also need to use `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and `exit /b !ERRORLEVEL!` it's a weird batch thing you can read about here: https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: I can confirm that this does the trick. It's essentially saying "exit the current scope but not the entire script", so I had to break up some batch commands, but it looks good.